# Copy Folder content in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a folder that contains many files, I want to walk this folder and put the content of each file as an item in a list. For example, I have a folder that contains `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`.What I want is that the first element of a list `List` contains the content of `file1`, the second element contains the content of `file2` and so on.
I started with this little code then I'm blocked

```
List = []
for files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\hmk\\Desktop\\Folder"):
    for filename in files:
        filer = open(filename,"r")
```

Thank you

Comment: First of all, why will you want that? That seems like a total waste of memory assuming you mean to actually store the whole file as a string. Second, read the [`os.walk` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to see what you're doing wrong. In short, `os.walk` returns a 3-tuple so you need to change that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

dir_path = '/path/to/your/files'
result = []
files = os.listdir(dir_path)
for f_name in files:
   with open(os.path.join(dir_path, f_name), 'r') as f:
       result.append(f.read())
```

Something like this.